# Dissplay an image within a <div> with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display an image within a div as shown in the javascript code below. The "alert" tells me I am in the function but the image does not display. If possible I would like to size the image to the page size. I know I can set a var, i.e. "var swidth = screen.width;". The image is in the same folder as the code.

### Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
 <p align="left"><div id="myDiv">This is a div element.</div>
 <br>
 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set the background image of div</button>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
 alert("inside myFunction");
 console.log();
 document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('Nav-Aids-Logo-Long-Trans-1920.png')";
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `backgroundSize = "100% 100%"` and `backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"` to your `"myDiv"` elements styles, and change `backgroundImage` to `background`. Also check the directory of the image you want to add, if it's right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It works in this snippet, which is identical to your code except of the image URL. So the problem seems to be your filepath or image.

(BTW: Your `p` tag isn't closed anywhere...)

```js
function myFunction() {
 alert("inside myFunction");
 console.log();
 document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://placehold.it/600x300/0fa')";
 }
```

```html
 <p align="left"><div id="myDiv">This is a div element.</div>
 <br>
 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set the background image of div</button>
```

Concerning your wish cover to the whole page with your background image: In this case you have to assign the background image to the `body`, not to any particular DIV:

```js
function myFunction() {
 alert("inside myFunction");
 console.log();
 document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://placehold.it/600x300/0fa')";
 }
```

```html
<p align="left"><div id="myDiv">This is a div element.</div>
 <br>
 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set the background image of div</button>
```